# Generating Normals with specific means and variances

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, generating-functions, monte-carlo

Suppose I wish to generate normals $X, Y, Z$ with the correlation matrix R but with means $0, 1, 2$, and variances $4, 16, 25$, respectively.

How would you do this?

The only way I know of doing this is to use a Cholesky Decomposition of a correlation matrix. Can I find a correlation matrix using the means and variances?

I plan to generate correlated standard normals using the typical procedure of Cholesky decomposing the correlation matrix and then multiply that new matrix L by a 1x3 vector of i.i.d standard normals(U,V,W). I would use the new correlated standard normals and shift and scale them as follows:

$Z_1=2*U_1+0$

$Y_1=4*V_1+1$

$X_1=5*W_1+2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transformations that you plan to apply to $U_1$, $V_1$, $W_1$ will result in variables $Z_1$, $Y_1$, $X_1$ with the *same* correlation structure compared to before, so your algorithm will have the desired effect (assuming the desire is to retain the correlation matrix as $R$). This follows from the definition of correlation
$$
\operatorname{Corr}(X,Y)={\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)\over\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X)}\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(Y)}}
$$
and the properties of covariance and variance:
$$
\operatorname{Cov}(aX+b,cY+d)=ac\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y),
$$
$$
\operatorname{Var}(aX+b)=a^2\operatorname{Var}(X).
$$

Comment: Maintaining my correlation structure was the intent. I was worried the shifts and scales might, in some way. alter the correlations of the variables. Thank you.